# How to use Android5.0 sdk with eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I downloaded Android5.0 SDK, SDK System Image, Unzip and move it to sdk directory, I created a android virtual device, but I can not boot the avd, it doesn't work.How can I do to use the Android5.0 SDk?Thanks :)

Comment: It seems you **overcomplicated** it all... can't you simply use the **SDK Manager** and let it do the **dirty job** for you? Then don't forget to do `Help/Check for Updates`

Answer (score 0):

he following configurations helped me created an Android L emulator successfully :

Device : Nexus 5

Target : Android L preview ( Ensure API 20 packages are installed as outlined in answers above )

CPU/ABI : Intel Atom x86

Skin WQVGA400

RAM : 2048 VM Heap : 64

Emulation options Snapshots , Use host GPU unchecked .

The emulator took a while to load but was successful ultimately.